# How to make Card Header Title bold in Gmail Add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, gmail-addons, google-apps-script-addon

How to make Card Header Title bold in Gmail Add-on? I tried this, but it doesn`t work:

```
function mainCardBuild(content) {
    return CardService.newCardBuilder()
        .setHeader(
            CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('<b> MY TITLE </b>')) //doesn`t work bold
        .addSection(content)
        .build();
}
```

I`m sure that we have opportunity to do it, because in Slack Add-on I saw it.
[Bold card header in Slack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTabo.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot insert HTML in your title, but you can insert basic HTML into Text Paragraphs (see: [Informational widgets](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/widgets#informational_widgets) and [supported text formatting](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/widgets#text_formatting)).
Your code could then look as follows:

```js
function mainCardBuild(content) {
    var boldHeaderSection = CardService.newCardSection()
      .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('<b>MY TITLE</b>'));
    return CardService.newCardBuilder()
        .addSection(boldHeaderSection)
        .addSection(content)
        .build();
}
```

In case you need to do more customisations, I suggest you check out the following example, which uses HTML to create the view [Translate Add-on Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/editors/docs/quickstart/translate).